# Why does my VS code output window show that my code is stil running?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I just started coding C++ using VS code and now every time I request input from a user using `cin` the command screen appears, I input the required variables and then it closes, however my output console keeps showing that my code is running. Is that an issue?

The code I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x,y;
    int z = x*y;

    cout<<"Please enter the first number:\n";
    cin>>x;
    cout<<"Please enter the second number:\n";
    cin>>y;
    cout<<"The area is "<<z;

    return 0;
}
```

When I press the run button, the command screen appears, the program asks for the two numbers then the screen disappears. Then on the output window of VS code, the programs asks for the first number and that's it, it keeps running.

Comment: Could you post an example program that exhibits this behavior?

Comment: Could be a problem with your antivirus software.

Comment: #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x,y;
    int z = x*y;

    cout<<"Please enter the first number:\n";
    cin>>x;
    cout<<"Please enter the second number:\n";
    cin>>y;
    cout<<"The area is "<<z;

    return 0;
}

Comment: @John i have edited the original post and added the code. Since i am just starting, it is very basic.